# GPS how to combine latitude/longitude with horizontalAccuracy to create "buckets" of data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, latitude-longitude

I'm processing user photos on an iPhone and some of them are geotagged (have latitude and longitude). For example, my longitude looks like -73.123456. Each GPS tag has a horizontalAccuracy property, expressed in meters.

How can I combine the horizontal accuracy with latitude/longitude to create groups(buckets) of GPS coordinates?

For example, I want to have all photos that are taken around the user's house to fall into one bucket, while all photos taken around work fall into another bucket.

I originally was thinking about multiplying the latitude/longitude by 1,000,000 , then cutting off fractional components:

```
 CLLocation *assetLocation = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [assetLocation coordinate];

                NSInteger latitudeInt = coordinate.latitude * 1000000;
                NSInteger longitudeInt = coordinate.longitude * 1000000;

                latitudeInt = latitudeInt-(latitudeInt % 100000);
                longitudeInt = longitudeInt-(longitudeInt % 100000);



               NSLog(@"trimmed:(lat %f, lon %f) real: (lat %f, lon %f) ",  latitudeInt/1000000.0, longitudeInt/1000000.0,coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude);
```

This will result in GPS reading of -73.1

The problem with this approach is that for one photo I get GPS location that is 1km off, but if I subtract 0.099 from the latitude/longitude reading, the error can be up to 5kilometers.  Ideally, my buckets would each be 1-2 kilometers across, centered around some GPS coordinate.

**This poses a question - how can I combine information about latitude/longitue, together with horizontal accuracy to create groups/buckets of GPS coordinates?** They don't have to be accurate or centered directly onthe user's house, but I would like all photos taken around the users's house to fall into the "user's home" bucket.

Comment: Can't you just calculate the distance and check if it's particularly close to either to the user's house or work or whatever?

Comment: The thing is - I don't know where either the users house or work is, and I expect that if I strip some digits from the lat/Lon , all photos taken at home, work, etc would be grouped together.

Comment: Oh. Well it's obviously hard to do then. This may not be the best solution but I'd try to use the initial entries as reference points so that I could compare the distance between the new ones and conclude if they are close enough to fall into the same bucket. Just a suggestion though, probably there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [k-means clustering Algorithm.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Means-Algorithmus)

Your task is a quite difficult, this will cost a lot of time and needs algoritmic (geo-spatial) knowledge. Think again if you need that.